# Local SSH connection to Gitlab not working

Tags: ssh, git, localhost, gitlab

I'd like to be able to clone, push and pull (via SSH) on my Gitlab-Server from/to itself.

Currently, when try to clone a git repository locally from my server I get this:

```
jacob@server: git clone git@git.example.com:project.git
fatal: 'project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I try to connect via ssh, I get a normal shell:

```
jacob@server: ssh git@git.example.com:
git@server:~$
```

Replacing git.example.com with localhost, 127.0.0.1 or the local IP yields the same results.

Cloning/... from another PC works flawlessly. When I connect via SSH from an other PC, it shows:

```
jacob@mypc: ssh git@git.example.com:
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, jacob!
Connection to git.example.com closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the problem evident in your SSH shell-getting test is unrelated (the server likely just ran out of PTYs).  You shouldn't need a terminal to be allocated to use git.

It's necessary that `project.git` be a git repository located in the home directory of the user `git`.  Also check that there isn't a folder `project.git` in your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me to the error. I just had to change the source to `git@git.example.com:repositories/project.git` since the projects are saved in /home/git/repositories.